# check email exist from three table

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have 3 tables for users; one for students, another for professors, and another for mangers.

Now I create 3 different layout pages in Android. Every one has different table in MySQL DB.

I want to use one login page for all three but I don't know how to do this. I wrote some code but I don't know if the query is right or not.

```php
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    include 'db.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $Sql_Query = "select exists(
         select 1 from manger where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$Password'
         union
         select 1 from student where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$Password'
         union
         select 1 from professor where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$Password'
    )";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

    if(isset($check)){
        echo "Welcome To Application";
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
    }

}else{
        echo "Try Again";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Using mysqli_connect is dangerous please use PHP Prepared Statements https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: why this is danger? can you explain ? and for my problem can you help me

Comment: When you write queries like : select 1 from manger where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$Password' it's tedious and it's prone to error. If you were to use prepared statements the query would look like the following : 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO manager(Emai, Password) VALUES (?, ?)"); which elimitates the risk of typos that could result in malformed queries

Comment: okay but my right query not to insert  any data but it for check is data is already exist from the three table or not my php file that i add it is called "login.php"

Comment: Or yea it would be select exists instead of insert. I think you are misusing select exists https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Comment: i use union , and exist , is my above code is right or not ?

Comment: please tell me how to check email exist from 3 table by using what and how ? can i use join ?? .... iam beignner not professional

Comment: I don't think so. See the link above that uses like it :  SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT column_name FROMtable_name WHEREcondition);

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever put raw string variables into an SQL statement, you will add massive security bugs into your application https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Never store passwords in plain text in a database, you must at a minimum use hashes and preferably salted hashes. PHP even has functions to do this for you http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: i dont understand anything i beigner not professional , iam so very very very beigner

Comment: i asked anyone to modify my code to be able to check email exist from three different table ? can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If the student, professor and manager tables all contain the same information it would be much better to create a single table with all users in with an additional column to indicate the type of user. You could then do a simple single select statement.

If you really need 3 separate tables then the following code would be more appropriate:

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

     include 'db.php';

     $con = new mysqli($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
     $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

     $Sql_Query = "
        select Password from manger where Email = ?
        union
        select Password from student where Email = ?
        union
        select Password from professor where Email = ?";
     $result = $con->prepare($Sql_Query)->bind_param("sss", $email, $email, $email )->get_result();
     $check=false;
     while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
     {
       if ( password_verify($password, $row[ "Password" ]) )
       {
           $check = true;
           break;
       }
     }
     if($check){
        echo "Welcome To Application";
     }
     else{
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
     }

 }else{
    echo "Try Again";
 }
```

I haven't tested the above so its likely to contain bugs/syntax errors but should at least be more secure.

When inserting new users you need to set the password to `password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT )` rather than inserting the password directly.

Comment: okay thanks for helping me i will test it and hope it will run but i have one question are you sure that using union will be run ? and another question why you write it as select password from tablename where email =? why you write it like this and didnt write   select 1 from manger where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$Password'

Comment: and by the way , every table have different information than another

Comment: see the comments on your question about SQL injection, never put a variable into a SQL string, use prepared statements instead. I'm selecting the password in order to pass the password into `password_verify`

Comment: okay thanks , so now i should have another field for hash ?

Comment: no, you shouldn't store unhashed passwords at all, you should store the hashes in your existing passwords column

Comment: ok, thanks very much for help ing me i will test the code and hoping it will run succsefully